# How to merge remote branches

Tags: git

I have:

- master branch in local
- master branch at remote
- production branch at remote

The way I use production is only when I want to merge it from master.

I remember there's a command that I can just push **remote/master** to **remote/production**, without having a production branch locally.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear. If my answers doesn't help with your problem, please leave a comment.

If you want to push the local master branch to the remote (origin) production branch:

```
git checkout master
git push origin production
```

If you want to push the remote master branch to the remote (origin) production branch without updating the local master branch:

```
git checkout tmp
git pull origin master
git push origin production
(git branch -d tmp)
```

If you want to push the remote master branch to the remote (origin) production branch and update the local master branch:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin production
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the latest version of your remote/master branch, otherwise you will be pushing the wrong commit.

```
git fetch -f remote master:remotes/remote/master
```

After this is done and you have made sure that this is the appropriate commit for production, you can push like this:

```
git push -f remote/master:remote/production
```

While you do need to fetch the commit to a remote branch in your local repository there is no need to create a local branch.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I have:

- **dev** branch in local
- **dev** branch at remote
- **test** branch at remote

When i make a change in local branch **dev** and then push to **origin/dev**, i want to merge the branch **origin/test**

```
git push origin +dev:test
```

this push the contents of the local **dev** branch to remote **origin/test**